# Atomicy of Add operation in Couchbase (Java SDK)

Tags: couchbase

Using Couchbase server 2.2 with Java SDK 1.4.4.

The documentation of `MemcachedClient::add(String key, int exp, Object o)` inherited by `CouchbaseClient` states: *"Add an object to the cache (using the default transcoder) iff it does not exist already"*.

I haven't found any mention of the atomicy of this operation.
Will asynchronous calls keep the initial value of the added key? Or this is a non-atomic wrapper for a get followed by a set?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`add` (like most Couchbase operations) is atomic - the cluster will (atomically) perform a check to see if the specified key exists and only if it doesn't will it set it to the given value.

If the key does exist you'll get an error back (`EEXISTS` or the Java native equivalent).

Comment: Source, please? the docs I found ( http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/php-2.0/atomic-operations.html)  dont mention add - only the incr() operations, though I tend to believe it.